# Help Proving The Following Theorem On Taylor Expansions

Tags: probability, solution-verification, proof-writing, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove this theorem on page 6 (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3001633):

**Theorem**:
If $x_1, \dots, x_k$ are independently distributed with density functions:
$$f_{n_i}(x_i) = \left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)^{\frac{n_i}{2}} \frac{x_i^{\frac{n_i}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{n_ix_i}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)}$$
for $0 \leq x_i < \infty$ and $R(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ is a rational function with no singularities for $0 < x_1,\dots,x_k < \infty$, then $\text{Ave}\{R(x_1,\dots,x_k)\}$ can be expanded in an asymptotic series in $\frac{1}{n_i}$.
In particular:
$$\text{Ave}\{R(x_1,\dots,x_k)\} = R(1,\dots,1) + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{n_i} \left.\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i^2}\right|_{(1,\dots,1)} + O\left(\sum \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right)$$

I was able to begin the proof:

**Proof**

- Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k$ be independent random variables with density functions $f_{n_i}(x_i)$ as given in the theorem.
- Assume some function $R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$.

By Taylor's theorem, we can expand $R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ around the point $(1, 1, \dots, 1)$:
$$R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) = R(1, 1, \dots, 1) + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial R}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{(1, 1, \dots, 1)} (x_i - 1) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i^2}\bigg|_{(1, 1, \dots, 1)} (x_i - 1)^2 + \dots$$

Now, we take the average of this function over $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k$. In probablity theory, averages can be thought of as "Expected Values":

$$\text{Ave}\{R(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k)\} = \int \dots \int R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) f_{n_1}(x_1)f_{n_2}(x_2) \dots f_{n_k}(x_k) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_k$$

Substituting the density functions $f_{n_i}(x_i)$ into the average expression, we have:
$$\text{Ave}\{R(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k)\} = \int \dots \int R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) \left(\prod_{i=1}^k \left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)^{\frac{n_i}{2}} \frac{x_i^{\frac{n_i}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{n_ix_i}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)}\right) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_k$$

I tried to simplify this a bit further:

$$\text{Ave}\{R(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_k)\} = \frac{1}{2^{\frac{k}{2}}} \left(\prod_{i=1}^k n_i^{\frac{n_i}{2}}\right) \int \dots \int R(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) \left(\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{x_i^{\frac{n_i}{2}-1}e^{-\frac{n_ix_i}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n_i}{2}\right)}\right) dx_1 dx_2 \dots dx_k$$

**But I don't know how to continue this from here (or if I have even done the work correctly).
Can someone please help me out here?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result is very computational, so there may be a computational error here or there in my answer, hopefully no more than a constant.

First, the Taylor expansion you provide in multiple dimensions is actually incorrect. See, for example, [the wikipedia page on Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables). The second order expansion of $R$ about $\mathbb{1} := (1,\dots,1)$ is
$$R(x_1,\dots,x_k) = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{j=1}^k D_jR(\mathbb 1)(x_j - 1) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{k}D_{ij}R(\mathbb 1)(x_i-1)(x_j-1) + \varepsilon,$$
where
$$D_iR(\mathbb 1) := \frac{\partial R}{\partial x_i}(\mathbb 1), \quad D_{ij}R(\mathbb 1) := \frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\mathbb 1), \quad \varepsilon := O\left(\sum_{l,m,n=1}^k(x_{l}-1)(x_m-1)(x_n-1)\right).$$

This yields (using the customary notation of $\mathbb E$ instead of Ave)
$$\mathbb E[R(X_1,\dots,X_n)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{j=1}^k D_jR(\mathbb 1)(\mathbb E[X_j]-1) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{k}D_{ij}R(\mathbb 1)\mathbb E[(x_i-1)(x_j-1)] + \mathbb E[\varepsilon].$$
Now, we can calculate
$$\mathbb E[X_i] = 1, \quad \mathbb E[(X_i-1)^2] = \frac{2}{n_i}$$
for all $i$ straight from the definition of [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_density), hence $\mathbb E[X_i] - 1 = 0$. By independence it holds $\mathbb E[(X_i-1)](X_j-1)] = \mathbb E[(X_i-1)\mathbb E[(X_j-1)] = 0$ when $i\neq j$, hence
$$\mathbb E[R(X_1,\dots,X_n)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_i^2}R(\mathbb 1)\mathbb E[(X_i-1)^2] + \mathbb E[\varepsilon] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n_i}\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_i^2}(\mathbb 1)+ \mathbb E[\varepsilon].$$

We turn our attention towards the computation of $\mathbb E[\varepsilon]$. We have
$$\mathbb E[\varepsilon] = O\left(\sum_{l,m,n=1}^{k} \mathbb E[(X_l-1)(X_m-1)(X_n-1)]\right) = O\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k} \mathbb E[X_n^3]\right) = O\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right),$$
where we used independence and the fact
$$\mathbb E[X_n^3] = 1 + 3\frac{2}{n_i} + 2\frac{4}{n_i^2}.$$

In total we then have
$$\mathbb E[R(X_1,\dots,X_n)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n_i}\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_i^2}(\mathbb 1)+ O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right).$$
This is precisely what the authors claimed.

EDIT: As @forgottenarrow points out, a little more justification is needed to explain why

$$\mathbb E [\varepsilon] = O\left(\sum_{l,m,n=1}^{k} \mathbb E[(X_l-1)(X_m-1)(X_n-1)]\right).$$
This can be seen by simply going up to the next order of the Taylor expansion. We have
$$R(x_1,\dots,x_k) = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{j=1}^k D_jR(\mathbb 1)(x_j - 1) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{k}D_{ij}R(\mathbb 1)(x_i-1)(x_j-1) + \frac{1}{6}\sum_{l,m,n}D_{lmn}R(\mathbb 1) (x_l-1)(x_m-1)(x_n-1) + \varepsilon,$$
where
$$\varepsilon = O\left(\sum_{l,m,n,p}C_{lmnp}(x_l-1)(x_m-1)(x_n-1)(x_p-1)\right).$$
Taking expectations yields
$$\mathcal E[R(X_1,\dots,X_k)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{n_i}\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i^2} + O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right) + \mathbb E[\varepsilon].$$
We have
$$\mathbb E[\varepsilon] = O\left(\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{\mathbb E[C_{llll}]}{n_l^3}\right),$$
hence we can pull the $\mathbb E[\varepsilon]$ into the $O$ to get

$$\mathbb E[R(X_1,\dots,X_k)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{n_i}\frac{\partial^2 R}{\partial x_i^2} + O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right) + \mathbb E[\varepsilon] = \mathbb E[R(X_1,\dots,X_n)] = R(\mathbb 1) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n_i}\frac{\partial^2R}{\partial x_i^2}(\mathbb 1)+ O\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right).$$

EDIT 2: Small math error pointed out in comments corrected, thanks to @forgottenarrow.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention this, but the $X_i$ are Gamma distributed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: I attempted this problem earlier. The issue is that according to taylor's theorem,
$$\epsilon = \sum_{l,m,n} C_{l,m,n}(X)(X_l-1)(X_m-1)(X_n-1),$$
where $C_{l,m,n}$ depends on $X$. Taking an expectation of this, you also need to take the constant term into consideration. For example, imagine that 
$$C_{l,m,n}(X) = \text{sgn}((X_l-1)(X_m-1)(X_n-1)).$$
Then $E[\epsilon] \neq O\left(\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$ I think this is where you need to use the assumption that $R$ is a non-singular rational function, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Also another quick correction. The quadratic term involves the terms $E[(X_i - 1)(X_j-1)]$. You correctly stated that this is $0$ when $i\neq j$. When $i=j$, $E[(X_i-1)(X_j-1)] = \text{Var}(X_i) = \frac{2}{n_i}$. This is equal to $E[X_i^2]  - 1$, so the result ended up being the same, but that intermediate step should use $E[(X_i-1)^2]$ instead of $(E[X_i^2]-1)$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow We can make $C_{lmn}$ a determined constant by going additionally to the fourth order term in the expansion, in which case $C_{lmn}$ is determined completely by the third-order partials evaluated at $\mathbb 1$ and the fourth order term gets absorbed by the big $O$.

Comment: That … makes sense. I spent hours trying to figure that out and I never considered looking at the third-order Taylor polynomial. Wow. Thanks!

Comment: you guys are amazing... i am speechless... thank you so much !!! :)